# MVVM viewmodel events (commands?)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, itemssource

I have a MVVM setup that creates a View on my MainWindow. I am not sure how to know when a user Clicks on a specific Notification Item inside the View. Where would I add the event, or a command to know when that happens?

here are is my MVVM code :

### MainWindow

cs:

```
NotificationViewModel notificationViewModel = new NotificationViewModel();
notificationViewModel.AddNoticiation(new NotificationModel() { Message = "Error", Name = "Station 21" });
NotificationView.DataContext = notificationViewModel;
```

xaml:

```
<notification:NotificationView x:Name="NotificationView" />
```

### NotificationModel

```
public class NotificationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _Message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _Message; }
        set
        {
            if (_Message != value)
            {
                _Message = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Message");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            if (_Name != value)
            {
                _Name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public string TimeStamp
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss"); }
    }

    #region PropertChanged Block
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

### NotificationViewModel

```
public class NotificationViewModel 
{
    private ObservableCollection<NotificationModel> _Notifications = new ObservableCollection<NotificationModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<NotificationModel> Notifications 
    { 
        get { return _Notifications; } 
        set { _Notifications = value; } 
    }

    public void AddNoticiation(NotificationModel notification)
    {
        this.Notifications.Insert(0, notification);
    }
}
```

### NotificationView

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Notifications}"
                      Padding="5,5,5,5">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="SlateGray"
                            CornerRadius="4">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                       Text="{Binding Path=TimeStamp}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" 
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Message}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real selection mechanism built into an `ItemsControl`. It would probably solve your problem to switch out your `ItemsControl` for a `ListBox`.

If you do that, you can bind to `SelectedItem`, then handle any changes made to `SelectedItem` using the `PropertyChanged` event.

Example:

In your view model's constructor:

```
PropertyChanged += NotificationViewModel_PropertyChanged;
```

Add a property to your view model to allow the binding:

```
private string _selectedNotification;
public string SelectedNotification
{
    get { return _selectedNotification; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedNotification != value)
        {
            _selectedNotification = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedNotification");
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, add the event handler to your view model:

```
NotificationViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e))
{
    if (e.PropertyName = "SelectedNotification") DoStuff();
}
```

You may find that you don't even need to hook into `PropertyChanged` if you just want to update another control in your view based on the selected item in your list box. You can just bind directly to the property within xaml.

Comment: Thanks. But, I changed the `SelectedNotification` from type(string) to type(int), which can then be Binded to `SelectedIndex` of my `NotificationListBox`.  I then use this `SelectedIndex` as an index in my `ObservableCollection<NotficationModel> Notifications`.  I appreciate your help.